# Biblatex: pagination and bookpagination fields

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

The Biblatex manual (Version 3.18b, July 12, 2022), pages 19 and 25, explains the usage of the fields `pagination` and `bookpagination`. I should use `column` and not `pages` in some entries. Biblatex version 3.18. Texlive 2022; Linux Mint21.

Problem: using `@BOOK` and `@INBOOK` it's all right: the strings **col.** or **cols.** are used instead of **pp.**. Using `@ARTICLE` the reference to the column(s) cited is correct, but the page (=column) range is preceded by **pp.** and not by **cols.** I tried to change document style and biblatex style (verbose, authoryear), but to no success.

Here is a MWE, I hope it's minimal enough:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage
    [backend=biber,
    style=verbose,
    ]%
{biblatex}
%
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{one,
    author  = "Brown, John",
    title   = "Title of the article",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "The Journal",
    volume  = "14",
    pages   = "342--351",
    pagination = {column},
}
@inbook{two,
    author    = "Green, Mary",
    title     = "The Inbook title",
    booktitle = "The Book Title",
    year      = "2015",
    publisher = "Great Books",
    address   = "Somewhere",
    pages     = "20-25",
    bookpagination = {column},
    pagination = {column},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname} 
%
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum\footnote{\cite[350]{one}}.
Dolor sit amet\footnote{\cite[21]{two}}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is a citation. In footnote 2 it's all right. In footnote 1 the column referred to is correctly preceded by **cols.**, but the page range (= column range) is preceded by **pp.**.
[image: Citation]

This is the final bibliography, featuring the same problem:
[image: Final bibliography]

I'm afraid I'm missing something. Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: Thank you. I had wrongly understood the _Biblatex_ manual at p. 19: «bookpagination relates to pagination like booktitle to title». I did not realise that this field could be used also in other entry types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bookpagination` works just fine for `@article` entries. It follows the same logic as `@incollection` and `@inbook`: `bookpagination` controls the `pages` output, `pagination` the `postnote`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose,]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{one,
  author         = {Brown, John},
  title          = {Title of the article},
  year           = {1993},
  journal        = {The Journal},
  volume         = {14},
  pages          = {342--351},
  bookpagination = {column},
  pagination     = {column},
}
@inbook{two,
  author         = {Green, Mary},
  title          = {The Inbook title},
  booktitle      = {The Book Title},
  year           = {2015},
  publisher      = {Great Books},
  address        = {Somewhere},
  pages          = {20-25},
  bookpagination = {column},
  pagination     = {column},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Lorem ipsum\footnote{\cite[350]{one}}.
Dolor sit amet\footnote{\cite[21]{two}}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: John Brown. “Title of the article”. In: The Journal 14 (1993), cols. 342–351, col. 350]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had wrongly understood the _Biblatex_ manual, page 19: «bookpagination relates to pagination like booktitle
to title». I had not understood that this field can be used also in other entry types. Now it's all clear.